# Understanding If condition logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have something like this in my react stateful component (I am following some react tutorial)

```
class FullPost extends Component {
  state = {
    loadedpost: null
  }
  componentDidUpdate () {
    if (this.props.id) {
      if (!this.state.loadedpost || this.state.loadedpost && this.state.loadedpost.id !== this.props.id) {
        axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + this.props.id).then(response => {
            this.setState({loadedpost: response.data})
          })
        }
    }
  }
```

In the above code, look at this line

```
 if (!this.state.loadedpost || this.state.loadedpost && this.state.loadedpost.id !== this.props.id)
```

Here we are saying the  code to execute if `this.state.loadedpost` is true and even false? so I thought this check to be unnecessary and hence removed it. this makes my code something  like this

```
if ( this.state.loadedpost.id !== this.props.id) {
```

but this throws an error saying `this.state.loadedpost.id` (actually error is Cannot read property 'id' of null). Which I get it since we don't have anything in this.state.loadedpost.id yet (in our first request)

**[Question]** But then why isn't the same error not coming when we use the first mentioned code? i.e

```
  if (!this.state.loadedpost || this.state.loadedpost && this.state.loadedpost.id !== this.props.id)
```

Comment: Can't look for a property of object that doesn't exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why isn't the same error not coming when we use the first mentioned code?

Because `||` short-circuits. When it sees that `this.state.loadedpost` is falsy, it immediately takes that falsy value as its result and doesn't evaluate the right-hand side at all. So `this.state.loadedpost.id` isn't evaluated (so it doesn't cause the error).

Your version:

```
if ( this.state.loadedpost.id !== this.props.id) {
```

always tries to read `id` from `this.state.loadedpost`, which will fail if `this.state.loadedpost` is `undefined`, `null`, etc.

---

That statement *can* be shortened, there's no reason for the `this.state.loadedpost &&` part:

```
if (!this.state.loadedpost || this.state.loadedpost.id !== this.props.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the if statements short circuits.

Let's say you are asking if A **OR** B is true.
If A is true then B does not need to be evaluated because we have enough information to continue the execution.

Answer (score 1):

Because the logical evaluation rules of Javascript, there is a **shortcut**, if the first condition of an `||` is true it doesn't evaluate whatever comes later so the right hand side of the `||` is never evaluated

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

> As logical expressions are evaluated left to right, they are tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rules:
>
> false && (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to false.
>
> true || (anything) is short-circuit evaluated to true.

Answer (score 0):

Because `if` in optimized way.

Your `this.state.loadedpost` is `null` so it stops further evaluation:

```
if (!this.state.loadedpost || anythingElse) -> if (true || anythingElse)
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition is `true` when the `id` of `this.state.loadedpost` is different than `this.props.id`.

The first condition (`!this.state.loadedpost`) ensures that the evaluation of the last expression (`this.state.loadedpost.id !== this.props.id`) does not attempt to access the `id` property of an object that does not exist (`this.state.loadedpost` is not set yet).

When `!this.state.loadedpost` is `true` (because `this.state.loadedpost` is `undefined`), the entire expression is `true` (because of `||`) and the rest of it is not evaluated (JavaScript shortcircuits the logical expressions).

The second condition (`this.state.loadedpost`) is not needed. It is evaluated only when the first condition is evaluated to `false` and the second condition is always `true` when the first one is `false`.

The expression can be simplified without changing its meaning to:

```
  if (!this.state.loadedpost || this.state.loadedpost.id !== this.props.id) {
     // ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`&&` has higher priority than `||` (think of 5 + 3 * 2 === 5 + (3 * 2))

Hence,

```
if (!this.state.loadedpost || this.state.loadedpost && this.state.loadedpost.id !== this.props.id)
```

is equivalent to (look at the parentheses)

```
if (
    !this.state.loadedpost ||
    (this.state.loadedpost && this.state.loadedpost.id !== this.props.id)
)
```

Thus, answer to your question

> Here we are saying the code to execute if `this.state.loadedpost` is true and even false?

is "No, we don't."

However, because short-circuit evaluation, you can shorter your condition:

```
if (
    !this.state.loadedpost ||
    this.state.loadedpost.id !== this.props.id  // this evaluates only if !this.state.loadedpost is false
)
```